# string with 's not getting inserted with insert statement

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to insert a question in database with field in table as nvarchar(max) (sql server 2008 r2)

Code is as follows:

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    gc.ExecuteCommand("insert into QuestionMaster values('" & txtQuestion.Text & "','" & ViewState("ClientID") & "','" & ViewState("KioskID") & "')")
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>alert('Question Added Sucessfully!!!')</script>")
    BindGrid()
End Sub
```

when i insert any string with :

```
what's your name?
```

then it gives me error:

> Incorrect syntax near 's'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

If i simply supply string as:

```
What is your name?
```

Then it does not gives me error.

Please help me.

Comment: simple fix change that to be a parameterized query

Comment: Congratulations. You've just discovered the starting point of SQL Injection - and why you should use parameters to keep data (column values) separate from code (SQL *is* code, despite it being embedded in your VB as a string). So go search for Parameterized Queries

Comment: This is not about `c#`, tag deleted.

Comment: @SonerGönül answer in c# also helps me,, since i thought question is more related with sql rather than C# or vb , i taged c# also

Comment: `M.N.S.` make up your mind.. sounds like you do not know what you are talking about.. I can see the hole that you're digging getting deeper

Comment: @Downvoter: how many downvotes are you going to give me? its 4th downvote for me for 4th different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could **escape single quote by replacing single quote (') with two single quotes ('')** in the txtQuestion.Text.

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    gc.ExecuteCommand("insert into QuestionMaster values('" & txtQuestion.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "','" & ViewState("ClientID") & "','" & ViewState("KioskID") & "')")
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>alert('Question Added Sucessfully!!!')</script>")
    BindGrid()
End Sub
```

Comment: @M.N.S.: Just keep in mind this solves your _immediate_ problem. I suspect you'll be back shortly :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo yeah, i know, but cant do anything , have to stuckup with company rules

Comment: @M.N.S. - Your company rules require your code to be vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway yup. it seems to be.

Answer (score 9):

You should be using parameterised queries if possible since simple string insertion directly into a query will, as you have seen, possibly corrupt the query.

In other words, if the text box contains `Paddy O'Rourke`, your query becomes:

```
                                 open   close   what the ?
                                  |       |      |
insert into QuestionMaster values('Paddy O'Rourke') ...
```

and you can see the fact that the embedded `'` is corrupting the query.

It will also, as you have yet to realise, allow people to perform SQL injection attacks on your database since you're not sanitising the input.

If, for some reason, your shop disallows parameterised queries (as it appears from one of your comments), find another place to work. No, just kidding, but in the presence of such a bone-headed policy, you'll need to sanitise the input yourself.

But that's fraught with danger, I would first try to change such a policy, laying out in no uncertain terms the risks involved.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you should rather make use of [Parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

This will also avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: yup, i know but in our company i have to work with fix structure of insert update delete , which does not includes parametrized queries.

Comment: HA HA what a bogus excuse.. if you can write dynamic queries you can definitely replace that sql statement with parameters especially if you actually wrote the code..

Comment: @DJKRAZE yup, with parametrized it worked, just tested, but i have to work within code structure provided to me by company. So cant use parametrized queries.

Comment: @M.N.S. That makes no sense. Parameterized queries have fixed structure. Building values into SQL queries with string concatenation is just a bad practice.

Comment: you are making no sense.. what do you mean by code structure.. I have a feeling that you are not familiar with the term `Thinking outside the box` if the code they provided causes potential issues why continue the cycle..? perhaps you should take initiative and speak up on the issues we have pointed out here

Comment: @DJKRAZE if you can see my code there is function: gc.ExecuteCommand() within that function i have been told to write insert/update/delete query directly

Comment: @JLRishe  if you can see my code there is function: gc.ExecuteCommand() within that function i have been told to write insert/update/delete query directly.

Comment: Do you know what the term `Refactor` means? based on gc.ExecuteCommand looks like something someone wrote that can in deed be overwritten

Comment: If you were told to jump of a bridge into `HOT LAVA` would you do it or suggest an alternative route..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE i know about parametrized queries very well, in my previous company, i used to use that, but in this, i have been introduced with fixed structure and i am not allowd to change it.

Comment: `M.N.S` good luck if you are familiar with it then you should use it.. also if you know OOP you can definitely incorporate some of those principals to override some other class functionality or even better create an Interface.. but you are once again not making any sense.. good day

Answer (score 3):

There may be a chance that your data may contain some special characters like single quotation mark which make your statement fail.

So better to use [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx): ***Parameterized queries do proper substitution of arguments prior to running the SQL query.***

```
SqlCommand insertNewAreaPath = new SqlCommand(
    "insert into QuestionMaster (Question, ClientID, KioskID) VALUES(@Question, @ClientID, @KioskID)", con);
insertNewAreaPath.Parameters.Add("@Question", txtQuestion.Text);
insertNewAreaPath.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", ViewState("ClientID"));
insertNewAreaPath.Parameters.Add("@KioskID", ViewState("KioskID"));
insertNewAreaPath.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

ELSE: use `.Replace("'", "''")`

```
gc.ExecuteCommand("insert into QuestionMaster values('" & txtQuestion.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "','" & ViewState("ClientID") & "','" & ViewState("KioskID") & "')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ' with '' and it will work fine.

Try this 
what''s your name?

Comment: @M.N.S., I think Abhishek means try the text string `what''s your name?` He wasn't asking what your actual name was :-)

Comment: You are right, @paxdiablo. Sorry for the confusing answer M.N.S

Answer (score 0):

```
//declare this variable

String sql="insert into QuestionMaster values('" & txtQuestion.Text & "','" & ViewState("ClientID") & "','" & ViewState("KioskID") & "')";
```

debug it and you will find where it appears problem.